# Choosing geospatial statistical test using building characteristics and distance together

Tags: statistics, modelling, footprint

New to geospatial analyses and I am trying to assign a building footprint to be a type of building (e.g., industrial building).

- In another dataset, we have determined the average building area, average vertices, etc of industrial buildings.
- Now we are trying to assign probabilities of being an industrial facility to building footprints near a GPS point (where someone said an industrial building is but it does not directly intersect with building footprint).
- We assume buildings closer to the GPS point are more likely to be industrial buildings.
- But we also want to match the building characteristics (area, vertices) with the known distributions. As sometimes the closest building is way different than known industrial facilities based on their area/vertices.

I've thought of building a model that predicts probability of a footprint being industrial using building characteristics, then combining with the inverse distance weight. But I'm kind of making that up and not sure how to combine.

Wondering if there are tried and true (hopefully published) methods for combining the distance from point with building/polygon characteristics?